# Setting for BatchNorm layer in Caffe?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am implementing the [Identity Mappings in Deep Residual Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.05027).

```
conv-->BatchNorm-->ReLU
```

As I known, the BN often is followed by Scale layer and used `in_place=True` to save memory. I am not using current caffe version, I used 3D UNet caffe, hence, I follow the setting in the [website](http://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/resources/opensource/3dUnet_miccai2016_with_BN.prototxt). I found that, `use_global_stats: false` for TRAIN and `use_global_stats: true` for validation and deploying. However, when I used  `use_global_stats: true` in deploying, the result is very poor (~30% accuracy). If the parameter is set to `false` and the result becomes good (80% accuracy). Can I set  `use_global_stats: true` in deploying? I am using volumetric data which has size `256x128x256`, and I need to crop it into `32x32x32` to feed to network dueto limited GPU. Thanks

This is my current BatchNorm +Scale layers

```
layer {
  name: "bnorm1"
  type: "BatchNorm"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  batch_norm_param {
    use_global_stats: false
    moving_average_fraction: 0.999
    eps: 1e-05
  }
}
layer {
  name: "scale1"
  type: "Scale"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
  scale_param {
    axis: 1
    filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
    bias_term: true
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, as the following is set in batch_norm_layer.cpp, you don't have to set `use_global_stats` at all in the prototxt.

In batch_norm_layer.cpp:

```
use_global_stats_ = this->phase_ == TEST;
```

Comment: Thanks. But it does not answer my question. My question is that Is it correct if we set use_global_stats=false in develop/testing phase?